# Drag Drop of Jquery UI not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am using the drag and drop functionality of Jquery UI on my website. But it is showing some issue. The Drag functionallity is having some gap. Like I accessed the gap from x place and want t place it at y position. But when I click the x position and try to drag it. It is shown somewhere else with a fixed height gap in the upward direction. So, it doesn't looks nice. Can any body help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Hello, I am using it on this page: http://codenomad.net/promo_app/questionnaire_question.php?ques_id=509 login using 
uname: admin
pass: admin

Comment: If you scroll down, than you will see what I am saying.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @Neha - Hello, can you add some code or some jsfiddle demo so that we can look into it and troubleshoot your problem.